# Identical sums of elements in two arrays

Tags: algorithm

I have two arrays of integers `v1` and `v2` with same length. I want to find the largest subset of elements of `v1` for which the sum is identical to that of the corresponding elements in `v2`. For example, let

```
v1 = [1 2 3 1] 
v2 = [2 3 1 2]
```

the sum of the 2nd, 3rd and 4th element is `6` in both arrays so this would be the subset that I am looking for.

Is there a way to compute this?

Thanks a lot in advance.
Cesare

Comment: Is there expected time complexity ?

Answer (score 2):

Compute the deltas, and the problem is reduced to the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). In other words, create a third array where each element is the difference between the corresponding elements in the two input arrays.

For example, given the input arrays `v1` and `v2`, create a third array `v3` that contains the differences:

```
       0  1  2  3   <-- index into the array
v1 = [ 1  2  3  1] 
v2 = [ 2  3  1  2]
v3 = [-1 -1  2 -1]
```

Then any subset in `v3` that adds to `0` is a solution. In this example, the solutions are represented by the sets of indexes: `{0,1,2}`, `{0,2,3}`, and `{1,2,3}`.